# Flask-SocketIO 'Connect' callback

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to access variables that are being passed from the client (iOS; Swift) to the server on a Flask-SocketIO connection on the `connect` action. Let me explain. When you want to do a random action you have something like this on the server which includes a callback (see `data` in the code below):

```
@socketio.on('custom action', namespace = '/mynamespace')
def handle_custom_action(data):
    print data
```

There are some preset actions (like `connect`) and apparently `connect` does not have any callback when it's called so the client cannot send any data on the `connect` action:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace = '/mynamespace')
def handle_connection(data):
    print data # nothing gets printed
```

I looked into the code a bit deeper and found this. The definition of the `on` function is:

```
def on(self, message, namespace=None):
```

And then within that function (I'm omitting a bit of code to get to the point):

```
if message == 'connect':
    ret = handler()
else:
    ret = handler(*args)
```

I could be wrong but it appears that code explicitly does not return anything back on connect and I'm not sure why? I've found some evidence that this is possible in node.js (I will update this with proper links when I find them) so I'm wondering why this isn't possible in the Flask-SocketIO library or whether I'm just misunderstanding what I'm looking at (and if so, how to get those parameters).

Thanks!

---

Update:
I did find a way to access connection parameters but it doesn't seem like the 'right' way. I'm using the global `request` and splitting the GET parameters / query string that come through on the request:

```
data = dict(item.split("=") for item in request.event["args"][0]["QUERY_STRING"].split("&"))
```

OR as two lines:

```
data = request.event["args"][0]["QUERY_STRING"].split("&"))
data = dict(item.split("=") for item in data.split("&"))
```

Flask-SocketIO adds `event` which connects a dictionary with keys of `message` and `args` and within `args` is the QUERY_STRING which I then split add turn into a dictionary. This works fine but it doesn't necessarily answer the original question as to why there is no callback?

---

Here is an example of the iOS connection params being passed:

```
let connectParams = SocketIOClientOption.connectParams(["user_id" : Int(user.userId)!, "connection_id" : self.socketConnectionId])
self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "http://www.myurl.com")!, config: [.nsp("/namespace"), .forceWebsockets(true), .forceNew(true), connectParams])
```

Comment: How are you passing custom arguments on a connect call from the iOS client? My understanding is that the connect call does not accept arguments.

Comment: @Miguel I just added a snippet of code above

Comment: Oh, okay, so they're sending arguments via the query string. Have you tried the normal Flask access to the query string? `request.args` should have the query string sent by the client. It will include the standard arguments (which you can ignore, as they are handled by Flask-SocketIO) and any custom args the client sent in the connection URL. At least that's what I think. If that doesn't work please write a bug and I'll make sure that works as expected.

Comment: @Miguel I'll give it a shot and let you know what I find. Thanks!